# Submenu list line up with parent list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nav, jquery-hover

I made a sidebar with a slide-out sub-menu. Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alh3168/UUMRM/1/.

How can I keep the height of the slide-out submenu (the opaque one) to 100% while making the list items in this submenu relative to their prospective parent menu items. AKA have the submenu items not at the top of the screen. I want it to look like this: http://perezweddings.com/blog/.

Maybe I need to change something here?:

```
div.menu ul.second {
  position: fixed;
  left: 258px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  width: 190px;
  background-color:rgba(0,180,180,0.3);
  bottom:0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the first submenu item to line up exactly with the parent item you are hovering over?

Comment: Doesn't have to be exact, although that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it JUST like the link you provided, simply add padding-top:200px to you ul.second.  That is what they did.

Comment: Works in jsfiddle but not Dreamweaver, or in browser preview.

Comment: It should.  Unless something else is going on.  Anything other than what is in your jfiddle?